# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist in Selenium 4.10.0

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, crash

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'shekhar-NE14A2', ip: '127.0.1.1'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2.0-24-generic', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Unable to resolve by any solutions provided on the platform

> Selenium version: 4.10.0

> chrome version: Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)

> chromedriver version: 114.0.5735.90

I was trying to use google chrome to open url [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and expected to open a new chrome session with loaded webpage. But chrome is transparent.

````
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/snap/chromium/2529/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7N7f.png
````